# Can't install rails3 - unmet dependencies

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, apt

I just got a Raspberry Pi 3 (I already have a fair amount of UNIX experience) and installed Raspbian. I'm trying to install Rails 3 with apt-get. When I try, I get a message about unmet dependencies. I ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` before `sudo apt-get install rails3`. Is rails3 compatible with Raspbian?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install rails3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rails3 : Depends: ruby-rails-3.2 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

### Previous software installed:

i2c drivers

```
sudo apt-get install python-smbus
sudo apt-get install i2c-tools
```

Adafruit PCA9685 Python library

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential python-dev
git clone https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_PCA9685.git
cd Adafruit_Python_PCA9685
sudo python setup.py install
```

### Tested with clean system

I made a fresh Raspbian SD card and only ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` before trying `sudo apt-get install rails3`. I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you installed software from a non-standard repository or tried to mix software between the jessie and wheezy releases?

Comment: I edited my question to add everything I installed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103345/discussion-on-question-by-ssteve-cant-install-rails3-unmet-dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if rails 3 works, but...

from http://elinux.org/RPi_Ruby_on_Rails :

## Install prerequisites

```
sudo apt-get install -y git curl zlib1g-dev subversion
```

## Update APT package index

```
sudo apt-get update
```

## Additional Ruby dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install -y openssl libreadline6-dev git-core zlib1g libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3
sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
sudo apt-get install -y autoconf automake libtool bison
```

## Note: Not installing openssl before RVM will cause you grief later!

Now we can use RVM straight from github using:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

Note: With my default Debian image and keyboard map, it was very hard to get a | (pipe) character. I got it by pressing AltGr+|

When run, you will get some messages about requirements for Ruby. You need to press 'q'. Note the computer may not react straight away as it is 'thinking'. After a few seconds, the script will download and compile ruby 1.9 and Rails. This takes a long time! (3 Hrs) Have a sleep and check in the morning.

At the end of the installation, RVM suggests that you have to run a script in order to enable Ruby. (I think I only had to do this once?)

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Now you should have ruby:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [armv61-linux-eabi]
```

And you should have a rails command:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.3
```

Comment: I'd rather use the rails3 apt-get package since it exists.

Comment: And i'd rather be sitting on a golden toilet rather than porcelain, but sometimes it's just not in the cards. I understand your plight. Let me know if you get it to work that way. I haven't been able to.

Comment: After further research I think I'll use web.py instead. It installed and was working in less than a minute. So the rails3 golden toilet will have to remain an unfulfilled wish.

Comment: indeed... maybe someday...